# Azure Powershell Function Append to Blob using Push-Outputbinding

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions

I made an Azure Powershell function that needs to write some data into a blob, so am using an outputBlob binding along with:

```
Push-OutputBinding -Name <name> -Value <value>
```

That writes the data I need into the blob - great! But the issue is that every time the function runs it overwrites the blob content. I cannot see how to get the Push-OutputBinding cmdlet to append data into the blob, rather than 'set' it. I have tried setting the -Clobber switch, but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Bindings seem like a nice way to interact with Blob storage without having to pull in more code to instantiate a more full-on client session, I hope this is possible? Would appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm reasonably confident there is no native way to append to a blob in powershell and in the output binding of an azure function, so you'd have to code for that (also, i think the only way to append to block blob is to download the content and append locally and reupload, but I'm not sure about this one).

Comment: Understood. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

As 4c74356b41 said, there is no native way to append to a blob in powershell.

But you don't need to download the content to a file **locally**, `$storageBlob.ICloudBlob.DownloadText()` can be used to download.

Following is my test code to append "123456789" to the Blob:

```
$connctionstring = ""
$container = ""
$blob = ""
$appendText = "123456789"

$blobContext = New-AzureStorageContext -ConnectionString $connctionstring
$storageBlob = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Blob $blob -Container $container -Context $blobContext 

$storageBlobContent = $storageBlob.ICloudBlob.DownloadText()

$storageBlobContent

$storageBlob.ICloudBlob.UploadText($storageBlobContent + $appendText)
```

[image]

Comment: Nice solution. Very helpful!

Comment: wdym "you don't need to download the content locally" - when you download it, lol. you dont have to save it to a file and do that in memory - sure. but you have to download it.

Comment: Yes, it will download to memory. I mean "you don't need to download the content locally" as a file. I will edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Create an Append blob using powershell command Set-AzStorageBlobContent with
blob type Append

```
$storageAccountName = ""
$containerName= ""
$storageContext= ""
$blobName = ""
$appendText = "123456789"

$storageContext = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $AccountKey
$patchContainer = Get-AzStorageContainer -Name $containerName -Context $storageContext
$storageBlob = Get-AzStorageBlob -Blob $blobName -Container $containerName -Context $storageContext 
$patchLogBlob = Get-AzStorageBlob -Blob $blobName -Container $containerName -Context $storageContext                         
$patchLogBlob.ICloudBlob.AppendText($appendText)
```

Comment: You mention using `Set-AzStorageBlobContent` in the first part of your solution, but that commandlet doesn't appear in the code sample. Is there missing code from your example?

Answer (score 0):

It seems, there's no necessity neither to create a new StorageContext nor to Get a new storage blob, all you need to do is to get the blob object and correctly call it's interface method.